# about proof of linear operators

Tags: operator-theory

$T\colon H^1[0,1]\to L^2[0,1]$
$$
T_{x}(t)=x(t)
$$
$H^1[a,b]$ is the space of all continuous differentiable functions with the norm 
$$
\|x\|_{H^1}=\left(\int_{a}^{b}x^2(t)dt+\int_{a}^{b}((x′(t))^2dt \right)^{(1/2)}
$$
firstly we need to show $T$ is linear and bounded and then how can we find its norm?

Answer (score 0):

For any $x\in H^1([0,1])$, $T(x)=x$ thus $T$ is obviously linear.

To prove that $T$ is bounded, you just have to show that $$\|x\|_{L_2}=\|T(x)\|_{L^2}\leq C\|x\|_{H^1}.$$
And an other way to write $\|x\|_{H^1}$ is $$\|x\|_{H^1}=\sqrt{\|x\|_{L^2}^2+\|x'\|_{L^2}^2}$$
so that you can easily find the constant $C$ you need.

Comment: I cannot find C.I am confusing

Comment: I've made an edit for the $^2$ missing. So you are looking for a constant $C$ s.t. $\|x\|_{L^2}\leq C(\sqrt{\|x\|_{L^2}^2+\|x'\|_{L^2}^2})$. Can't you see at least one real number $C\geq 0$ that agrees with this inequality ?

Comment: I see that there exist a real number such that C>0 but I must find this C because I need to find norm of T

Comment: What do you get if you take the square of this inequality ?